# Usage of "+" symbol in operations with characters

Tags: java, coding

What is the use of plus `"+"` symbol in code?

Eg: `(char) (myRandom.nextInt(26) **+** 'A')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the + is moving to the next char in the alphabet from where you are.

The random part doesn't help explain, so this snippet may help.

```
char x = (char)(1 + 'A'); // returns B.  Pos 1 + A (1) gives 2 => B
x = (char)(2 + 'A'); // returns C.  Pos 2 + A (1) gives 3 => C
x = (char)(3 + 'A'); // returns D.  Pos 3 + A (1) gives 6 => D
x = (char)(1 + 'A'); // returns B.  Pos 1 + A (1) gives 2 => B
x = (char)(2 + 'B'); // returns D.  Pos 2 + B (2) gives 4 => D
x = (char)(3 + 'C'); // returns F.  Pos 3 + C (3) gives 6 => F
```

Your random statement is seeded with 26.  So nextInt(26) will return a random number between 0 and 26.  Whatever is returned by that is that moved on one position by the + 'A' part.

Comment: There is a mistake in your comments to the code. 'A' is not coded with 1, otherwise you would not need to use 1+'A', you would just use 2. The sense of using "number+'A'" is that you are not aware of what number "A" is encoded with. So "1+A" will not give you 2.

Comment: Hi, you've take 'gives' too literally.  I was just showing how (1+'A') would return 'B'.

Answer (score 0):

This particular line means that you take a random shift from `'A'`. Say if

```
myRandom.nextInt(26) == 1
```

then you will get `'B'`